# Docker install failing on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: systemd, docker

I used to have an old version of docker on my Ubuntu Server 19.10 and it worked just fine. I have removed this old docker install and tried to install the most current version using the guide on https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

The install fails when the containerd service fails to start. When trying to start containerd, this is the error that comes up:

```
/usr/bin/containerd: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/containerd: undefined symbol: seccomp_api_set
```

Here's the error during the install:

```
    invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2020-05-07 08:37:28 EDT; 15ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 17336 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=killed, signal=TERM)
 Main PID: 17336 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

May 07 08:37:28 teddy-server systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
May 07 08:37:28 teddy-server systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
May 07 08:37:28 teddy-server systemd[1]: docker.service: Succeeded.
May 07 08:37:28 teddy-server systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (242-7ubuntu3.7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.7-3) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.30-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And journalctl -xe:

```
Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit containerd.service has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 34974.
May 07 08:37:28 teddy-server systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.socket has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit docker.socket has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 34894.
May 07 08:37:28 teddy-server systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit docker.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 34891.
May 07 08:37:28 teddy-server containerd[17335]: /usr/bin/containerd: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/containerd: undefined symbol: seccomp_api_set
May 07 08:37:28 teddy-server systemd[1]: containerd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit containerd.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 127.
May 07 08:37:28 teddy-server systemd[1]: containerd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit containerd.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
May 07 08:37:28 teddy-server systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit docker.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'killed' and its exit status is 15.
May 07 08:37:28 teddy-server systemd[1]: docker.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit docker.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
May 07 08:37:28 teddy-server systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit docker.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit docker.service has finished.
```

I'm stumped on this one. Please help!

EDIT:

`ldd /usr/bin/containerd | grep local` returns nothing.

`apt-cache policy libseccomp2` returns:

```
libseccomp2:
  Installed: 2.4.1-0ubuntu0.19.10.3
  Candidate: 2.4.1-0ubuntu0.19.10.3
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.1-0ubuntu0.19.10.3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`apt-cache policy $(dpkg -S /usr/bin/containerd)` returns:

```
containerd.io:
  Installed: 1.2.13-1
  Candidate: 1.2.13-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.13-1 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco/stable amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.2.13-1 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan/nightly amd64 Packages
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan/stable amd64 Packages
     1.2.12-1 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan/nightly amd64 Packages
     1.2.11-2 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan/nightly amd64 Packages
     1.2.11-1 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan/nightly amd64 Packages
     1.2.10-3 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco/stable amd64 Packages
     1.2.10-2 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco/stable amd64 Packages
     1.2.6-3 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco/stable amd64 Packages
     1.2.5-1 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco/stable amd64 Packages
N: Unable to locate package /usr/bin/containerd
```

`dpkg -S /usr/bin/containerd` returns:

```
containerd.io: /usr/bin/containerd
```

`grep -ir docker /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"` returns:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan stable 
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan stable
```

Comment: Please add output of `ldd /usr/bin/containerd | grep local` and `apt-cache policy libseccomp2` to the question.

Comment: It has been added.

Comment: So libraries are linked correctly. Then add `apt-cache policy $(dpkg -S /usr/bin/containerd)`.

Comment: Some output is not clear, what is the output of `dpkg -S /usr/bin/containerd`?

Comment: `containerd.io: /usr/bin/containerd`

Comment: Just tested eoan version of docker on 19.10 and it works normally. You have to check which Ubuntu version do you have in the corresponding sources.list with `grep -ir docker /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"`.

Comment: `/etc/apt/sources.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan stable
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan stable`

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this issue.

First, I searched for libseccomp related directories using 
`sudo find / -name '*libseccomp*'`

I found that I had old versions of libseccomp installed in 
`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libseccomp.so.2.3.1` and `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libseccomp.so.2`

I removed both of these directories and rebooted then I was able to successfully install Docker using the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Add Docker PGP key:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Configure docker apt repository:

```
echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

Update APT:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you had older versions of Docker installed, uninstall them:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
```

Install Docker:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

Test:

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

Start Docker:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Enable docker at boot time:

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

Allow non-root users to use docker:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Now, log out and log in back

Comment: Those are just the instructions from the page that I linked. The install fails when I use sudo apt-get install docker-ce.

Comment: `rm -rf /var/lib/docker` can solve this. You may also need to run this: `umount /var/lib/docker/devicemapper'

Comment: You need to clean all your existing data before you proceed:  `apt remove docker-*`
`rm -rf  /etc/docker`
`rm -rf /usr/bin/docker-*`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried all of that and I still get the same error. Could there be more previous Docker data that I need to remove?

Comment: Install this: `sudo apt install buildah`